# PHP - Combining two arrays and mapping supplier id1 to supplier id2

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on an array that involves combining and mapping of product ids.

I have two suppliers that have the same ids for the same product with different prices and slightly different names for the particular id. I want to display only the supplier that gives me the best price for the particular id(product), whenever both arrays have the same product id. I want to display every product available eliminating only duplicates and displaying only the product with the best price.

I'm having trouble with my code and cant figure out how to do this.

The following is my code. Please note I made an array for supplier 1 and supplier 2 instead of pulling it from my database; so you guys could just copy it to your IDE for debugging purposes.

```
<?php 
//array for supplier 1 data
$combined_sup1=array(
               array('id'=>71,'product'=>'Irish Spring Deodorant Soap - 8ct','price'=>3.99, 'img'=>'images/71.jpg'),
               array('id'=>14,'product'=>'L.A. Looks Sport Styling Gel 8 Oz','price'=>2.78, 'img'=>'images/14.jpg'),
               array('id'=>43,'product'=>'Cetaphil Daily Facial Cleanser - 8 fl oz bottle','price'=>8.89, 'img'=>'images/43.jpg'));
// array for supplier 2 data
$combined_sup2=array(
               array('id'=>21,'product'=>'Head and Shoulders- Dandruff Shampoo, 13.5 fl oz','price'=>5.94, 'img'=>'images/21.jpg'),
               array('id'=>71,'product'=>'Irish Spring Soap - 8ct','price'=>3.39, 'img'=>'images/71.jpg'),
               array('id'=>12,'product'=>'Colgate Total Toothpaste Advanced Whitening - 4 oz','price'=>3.59, 'img'=>'images/12.jpg'),
               array('id'=>43,'product'=>'Cetaphil Daily Facial Cleanser - 8 fl oz bottle','price'=>7.99, 'img'=>'images/43.jpg'));

//$merge=array_merge($combined_sup1,$combined_sup2);
     //  now to combine both arrays
     $combined_suppliers = array();
     // foreach($merge as $c){
    foreach ($combined_sup1 as $sup1 ) {   //  first loop supplier 1

        $comb = array('id_sup1' => $sup1['id'],'product' => $sup1['product'],'price_sup1'=>$sup1['price'],'img'=>$sup1['img']);  


        foreach ($combined_sup2 as $sup2) {   //  second loop supplier 2

            if ($sup2['id'] == $sup1['id']) {     //  if supplier 1 id =  supplier 2 id

                $comb["idsup2"]= $sup2['id'];
                $comb["product"]= $sup2['product'];
                $comb["price_sup2"]= $sup2['price'];
                $comb["img"]= $sup2['img'];
                break;
            }

        }  // end second loop



    $combined_suppliers[] = $comb;

}  // END //  first loop

// } //  end merge loop

// print_r($combined_sup1);
// print_r($combined_sup2);
// print_r($merge);

print_r($combined_suppliers);



?>
```

Update the following is the working code that Wilhelm Suggested.

```
<?php 
//array for supplier 1 data
$combined_sup1=array(
               array('id'=>71,'product'=>'Irish Spring Deodorant Soap - 8ct','price'=>3.99, 'img'=>'images/71.jpg'),
               array('id'=>14,'product'=>'L.A. Looks Sport Styling Gel 8 Oz','price'=>2.78, 'img'=>'images/14.jpg'),
               array('id'=>43,'product'=>'Cetaphil Daily Facial Cleanser - 8 fl oz bottle','price'=>8.89, 'img'=>'images/43.jpg'));
// array for supplier 2 data
$combined_sup2=array(
               array('id'=>21,'product'=>'Head and Shoulders- Dandruff Shampoo, 13.5 fl oz','price'=>5.94, 'img'=>'images/21.jpg'),
               array('id'=>71,'product'=>'Irish Spring Soap - 8ct','price'=>3.39, 'img'=>'images/71.jpg'),
               array('id'=>12,'product'=>'Colgate Total Toothpaste Advanced Whitening - 4 oz','price'=>3.59, 'img'=>'images/12.jpg'),
               array('id'=>43,'product'=>'Cetaphil Daily Facial Cleanser - 8 fl oz bottle','price'=>7.99, 'img'=>'images/43.jpg'));


//merge both arrays of products into one array
$comb = array_merge($combined_sup2,$combined_sup1);
//make new clear array for results
$listed = [];
//iterate over each product
foreach ($comb as $item) {
//if product with same id is in result array, then...
if(array_key_exists($item['id'], $listed)){
    //compare their prices
    if($listed[$item['id']]['price'] > $item['price']){
        //if price is lower than listed one, replace it
        $listed[$item['id']] = $item;
    }
} else {
    //there is no product with this id, so add it.
    $listed[$item['id']] = $item;
}
}


// print_r($combined_sup1);
// print_r($combined_sup2);
// print_r($merge);

print_r($listed);



?>
```

Comment: Why do you not compare prices?

Comment: @splash58 I'm confused on how to make it work. I tried so many different pieces of code with failure. I've been at this for hours with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
//merge both arrays of products into one array
$comb = array_merge($combined_sup2, $combined_sup1);
//make new clear array for results
$listed = [];
//iterate over each product
foreach ($comb as $item) {
    //if product with same id is in result array, then...
    if(array_key_exists($item['id'], $listed)){
        //compare their prices
        if($listed[$item['id']]['price'] > $item['price']){
            //if price is lower than listed one, replace it
            $listed[$item['id']] = $item;
        }
    } else {
        //there is no product with this id, so add it.
        $listed[$item['id']] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I'm trying it out now I will keep you updated on how it works out.

Comment: @francescalus added some comments with explanation

Comment: thanks! this works better then my combine, but it's still showing duplicate products ids. I have to eliminate the the product ID with the higher price from my array.

Comment: I didnt have any duplicate ids from the input you provided. Could you provide data where the duplication occurs? Result is in array "$listed"...

Comment: Ah! Thanks! My mistake(:  I just did a print_r on $listed and it works perfect. Thank you so much Wilhelm. I'm going to except your answer now.